# endpointStyle of the jsPlumb.connect method does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I'm using [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/home/dom.html). I want to assign different colors for each connection and its endpoints.

http://jsfiddle.net/RN3QE/

*(problem: the blue connection should also have blue endpoints)*

That is, my connect call looks like so (for now everything should be set to `blue`):

```
  jsPlumb.connect({
    source:"task1",
    target:"task3",
    endpointStyle: { fillStyle:"blue", outlineColor:"red", outlineWidth:2 },
    paintStyle: { strokeStyle:"blue", lineWidth:4 }
  });
```

Where `task1` and `task3` are divs created using jquery:

```
  var newState = $('<div>').attr('id', id).addClass('task')
```

And are defined to be possible sources/targets for connections:

```
  // Makes the task div a possible target (i.e. connection can be dragged to)
  jsPlumb.makeTarget(newState, {
    anchor: 'Continuous'
  });

  // Makes the task div a possible source (i.e. connection can be dragged from)
  jsPlumb.makeSource(newState, {
    anchor: 'Continuous'
  });
```

The syntax for `endpointStyle:` in `.connect()` was obtained from [here](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/connect-examples.html)

Why is it that the `paintStyle:` works correctly (colors the connection `blue`) in the `.connect()` call, but the `endpointStype:` does not (the endpoints are not `blue`)?

Comment: I suggest filing a bug here - https://github.com/sporritt/jsplumb/issues